# How to hook up sauna heater wired for 3 wire 230v to US 240v?

Tags: 240v

Purchased a sauna at Home Depot.  The heater that came with it is Advertised as 220v 20 amp.  My plan was to plug it into a 240v outlet I have in the garage (though after looking at my panel it is currently going to a 30 amp). When it arrived the heater had no plug on the end and only 3 wires.  The schematic included with the heater (BC 23 see picture) shows it is currently wired to 1. Ground 2. Neutral 3. L1 & L2 which are bridged.  From my research this is how it would be wired for European use.  My question is can I remove the 3 wire cord and the bridge and instead hook it up as 1. Ground 2. Neutral 3. L1 to 120 4. L2 to 120 so I can use a 4 wire US plug?  I plan to use an electrician to do the work but so far the 2 places I called didn't seem to know.  Appreciate any advice.
[image]

Comment: It might be possible to remove the jumper between L1/L2, but think this spa might be illegal to use or sell.  Does it have a UL mark on it?  If no instructions for a North American system, then just as easy to return it and get a proper one.

Comment: The cord coming out of the heater has a UL sticker on it.  It was delivered by freight on a pallet so it won't be an easy return.  I don't understand why Home Depot would be able to sell it if it wasn't legal to use.  On the webpage for Home Depot it says:ETL/CSA certified - meets all US and Canadian electrical safety standards - 220-Volt, 20 Amp plug

Comment: Will let the experts answer, but probably do the hook up as for BC23E 400v without the jumper.  Seems to be legal, but odd they don't have instructions for 240v systems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you hardwire this instead of using a plug you will be able to follow the 230V wiring below, with L1 going to L1, L2 going to N, and Ground going to G. That should be safe, requires less wire, and will eliminate the (likely) requirement for a GFCI.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong section of the instructions.  When this thing got a UL/CSA listing, the instructions were approved *as part of that*.  The UL/CSA listing is only valid if installed according to instructions, which you must do per NEC 110.3(B).   That page of the instructions will be EN/FR because that's a Canadian requirement. Purely as a practical matter they often put ES (North American Context) there as well, which opens it to the rest of the continent + many installers are Spanish-first-language.

Comment: I looked again at the instruction booklet and the posted schematic is the only one shown for the EN section.  There are a total of 14 languages for the instruction book (95 pages total 13 of which are in English).  FR has its' own separate listing.  So I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is can I remove the 3 wire cord and the bridge and instead hook it up as 1. Ground 2. Neutral 3. L1 to 120 4. L2 to 120 so I can use a 4 wire US plug?

If you do that, you will likely end up with the heater running at a quarter of it's designed power.

Most likely for a US style 120/240 supply you need to leave the "L1 and L2" terminals connected together and connect them to one hot from your supply, connect the "N" terminal to the other hot from your supply and leave the neutral conductor from the supply disconnected.

Comment: Yes.  However, this should only be done if told to by the instructions, which UL or CSA will have *approved* as part of granting the machine a UL Listing.  OP may need to do a web search for the *American/Canadian* instructions.  The languages should be EN/FR on that document and possibly ES.